# Unable to load images in pygame

Tags: python

Following the pygame documentation (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load), I am trying to load an image. I am using the following code:

```
stickman = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data', 'stickman.png'))
```

I get these errors:

[image]

The image and the file I am working on are in the same folder.

How do I resolve these errors?

Edit: I used

```
import os
```

and that fixed the os error. Then I restarted pycharm and the load error went away and now everything works.

Edit: At some point the load error came back, but everything still works. I do not know if the error is actually supposed to be there.

Comment: Have you imported the relevant modules?

Comment: @BenjaminEngwall I have imported sys and pygame

Comment: If I recall correctly, sys is a subset of os that does not include os.path. import os or os.path and that should issue should be fixed.

Comment: @BenjaminEngwall That fixed the os problem (thanks!), but the load problem is still there

Comment: What is your full code and is there a pygame.py and a image.py some where else where there shouldn't be one? And maybe full traceback?

Comment: I restarted Pycharm and the load error went away and now everything works.